# find duplicate values in a NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, xcode, indexing, nsmutablearray, duplicates

how to know how many times a duplicate appears in my array ?

```
for (NSUInteger index = 0; index < count; index++)

{ 

     NSDictionary *dico = [myArray objectAtIndex:index ];

    NSString *exp = [dico objectForKey:@"name"];

               NSLog(@"index %d : %@",index,exp);
    }
```

this is my NSLog:

```
index 0 : Mike
index 1 : Peter
index 2 : Franck
index 3 : Peter
```

want to know where is my duplicates values.

thx

Comment: Do you want to eliminate the duplicates or just count how many times a name appears on your array?

Comment: hi want to delete them but need to keep one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am not wrong NSSet was designed to do this... 
try this..

```
NSSet *uniqueElements = [NSSet setWithArray:myArray];

for(id element in uniqueElements) {
  // iterate here
}
```

Comment: `for (id element in [NSSet setWithArray:myArray]) {}`